# Website appearing and then disappearing in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I have a strange error, it only happens in IE9. The web page is shortly displayed then disappears.

Link is here: http://test.islandprotravel.de/index.php

In the Console log I can see this message:

HTML1114: Codepage unicode from (UNICODE byte order mark) overrides conflicting codepage utf-8 from (UNICODE byte order mark)

I double checked the charset, it is set in the META tag to utf-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

plus

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

For me it looks like IE9 switches to Quirks mode for some strange reason. The html code is valid and the site works in IE11, FF, Chrome, Safari

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue ?

Many thanks

Harald

Answer (score 0):

[This file](http://test.islandprotravel.de/mint/?js) seems to do a document.write in some special case ( probably for IE9) line 37 .

document.write overwrite the content of a webpage if it's done after the DOM has been loaded, so that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be the solution. I used defer async to invoke the js of this webstat tool. I removed it and now it works fine.